# Get a list of all custom markers in Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, pytest-markers

If I have a simple test case with my own custom markers like:

```
class TestClass:

    @pytest.mark.first
    def test_first(self):
        assert True

    @pytest.mark.second
    def test_second(self):
        assert True

    @pytest.mark.third
    def test_third(self):
        assert True
```

How can I get the list of whole custom markers, because `pytest -v --markers` returns a list of predefined markers

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(condition)
@pytest.mark.xfail(condition, reason=None, run=True, raises=None)
@pytest.mark.parametrize(argnames, argvalues)
@pytest.mark.usefixtures(fixturename1, fixturename2, ...)
@pytest.mark.tryfirst
@pytest.mark.trylast
```

without

```
@pytest.mark.first
@pytest.mark.second
@pytest.mark.third
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the marker names to your `pytest.ini` to register them. See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#registering-markers

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But actually, I thought that there is an easier way such as `@pytest.mark.first(annotate="This is my marker")`

Comment: The link is not working, it says: `SORRY This page does not exist yet.`

Comment: Note that even if you register the custom markers in  `pytest.ini` file, `item.config.getini('markers')` will still include the built-in markers such as `parametrize`, `skip`, `skipif`,  ..etc.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to register all custom markers in a file called `pytest.ini`:

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
markers = first_customer_marker
    another_custom_marker
    oh_one_more_marker
```

Now in order to get the list of custom markers you can use one of the following functions:

- `config.getini('markers')`: This is going to return a list containing the custom markers as well as the built in  markers such  as  `pararmetrize`, `skip`, `skipif`, etc.
- `config._getini('markers')`: This is going  to return a list  containing  ONLY the custom markers

**Example:**

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        print(item.config.getini('markers'))
        print(item.config._getini('markers'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should register `first`, `second` and `third` markers to `[pytest]` in [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini) as shown below to show them with `pytest --markers`.

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
markers =
    first: First marker
    second: Second marker
    third: Third marker
```